# React-navigation, createMaterialTopTabNavigator. Problem

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6AEO.png)

My problem is that I don't know were to put `"title"`. I have `TabNavigator`, with two pages. You can see on the image, which is what I really want to do.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View,Button } from 'react-native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <View >
                    <Button
                        title='Click me'
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')} />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Settings!</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Test1: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Test2: { screen: SettingsScreen },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to wrap the `MaterialTopTabNavigator`inside a `StackNavigator` and add the title option to it. So your code should looks something similar to this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View,Button } from 'react-native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <View >
            <Button
                title='Click me'
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')} />
          </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Settings!</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const App = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Test1: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Test2: { screen: SettingsScreen },
});

export default createStackNavigator({
  app: {
    screen: App,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Screen title',
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: I guess you already have another navigator as parent. Can you please share more code?

Comment: that is all of the code. but before I use createMaterialTopTabNavigator. I was install react-native-tab-view ( https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view )